# Is it forbidden or illegal to show "you should open internet connection" popup to user for show google ads in Android?

Tags: android, admob, adsense, user-experience, google-ads-api

When user don't have an internet connection i want to show a black fullscreen popup that include like

> "you should open your internet to use this app"

or

> "no internet connection found please open it"

every minutes for show my google ads;
and popup will countdown from 5 second for close the popup.

And i don't want to be banned from google ads because of illegal behaviours.

Is it forbidden or illegal with google ads policy, i didn't see any information about this on google ads docs?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that's illegal, but for better user experience, I suggest not to because of course some people would like to use the app without any ads interuption. But if you insist, user might be able to report your app for being "annoying" for forcing them to watch ads?

Answer (score 0):

i also don't think that's illegal but of course that gone little annoying for end users. The main goal to show ads in app is to generate revenue so you can put it like this way

"Our app was free in the past and remains free with even more functionality, but to continue working on this free app we need Ads revenue."

Or if your app has in-app purchase you can add this

"You can remove Ads by in-app purchase or on Premium subscription."

Answer (score 0):

It is not illegal however it is the concern of user experience. Certain users turn off internet connection to avoid ads after all. If you still want users to turn it on, it can be in a form of request where they are requested to turn it on in order to help developer of the app to provide free content and services to end users. This however may end up with users reporting your app for forcefully attempting to make them watch the ads which falls in the category of annoying. Other common workaround is by In-App Purchase where users need to pay to avoid seeing ads.